# Threejs, load mtl file and textures from different urls

Tags: javascript, three.js

So this problem might sound a little odd, let me explain. I am using the Roblox API to get the OBJ file, the MTL file and the Texture file. So the base api with the info is this `https://t2.rbxcdn.com/ef63c826300347dde39b499e56bc874b` and from that you get two important urls the obj file `https://t4.rbxcdn.com/4844b24bb4b6696ccbafda0c79d2c406` and the mtl file `https://t1.rbxcdn.com/58f8c8dfcad7ad36d17e1773a698223e`, the problem is the MTL file is loaded from the subdomain `t1`, whereas the texture is loaded from `https://t0.rbxcdn.com/21e00b04dc20ddc07659af859d4c1eaa` with the subdomain `t0`. Now here is where it gets tricky:

Here is the ThreeJs obj loader:

```js
mtlLoader.load('https://t1.rbxcdn.com/58f8c8dfcad7ad36d17e1773a698223e', async (mtl) => {
    await mtl.preload();
    const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader2.load('https://t4.rbxcdn.com/4844b24bb4b6696ccbafda0c79d2c406', (root) => {
        scene.add(root);
        root.children[0].material.transparent = false

        function init() {
            requestAnimationFrame(init)
            root.rotateY(0.03)
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        init()
    });
    await objLoader2.setMaterials(mtl);
});
```

The MTL loader tries to load the texture as `https://t1.rbxcdn.com/21e00b04dc20ddc07659af859d4c1eaa`, however as I stated above the subdomain for the texture is `t0` and not `t1` so how do I change the subdomain between the MTL file and the textures.

Here is the full html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    let root2

    const mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    const objLoader2 = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    mtlLoader.load('https://t1.rbxcdn.com/58f8c8dfcad7ad36d17e1773a698223e', async(mtl) => {
      await mtl.preload();
      const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      objLoader2.load('https://t4.rbxcdn.com/4844b24bb4b6696ccbafda0c79d2c406', (root) => {
        scene.add(root);
        console.log(root)
        root.children[0].material.transparent = false

        function init() {
          requestAnimationFrame(init)
          root.rotateY(0.03)
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        init()
      });
      await objLoader2.setMaterials(mtl);

    });


    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 0.5;
    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(color, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
    camera.position.set(0, 103, -5)
    camera.rotateY(-180 * Math.PI / 180)

    const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 1000, 100);

    light2.position.set(0, 110, -5);
    light2.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 103, -5))
    scene.add(light2);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi so I solved this and I am going to leave this here for anyone else who needs it. THIS IS A REALLY HACKY ANSWER. So I went into the MTL loader and found,

```js
    loadTexture( url, mapping, onLoad, onProgress, onError ) {

            const manager = this.manager !== undefined ? this.manager : THREE.DefaultLoadingManager;
            let loader = manager.getHandler( url );

            if ( loader === null ) {

                loader = new THREE.TextureLoader( manager );

            }

            if ( loader.setCrossOrigin ) loader.setCrossOrigin( this.crossOrigin );
            const texture = loader.load( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError );
            if ( mapping !== undefined ) texture.mapping = mapping;
            return texture;

        }
```

and under load texture i just added

```js
url = url.replace('t1','t0')
```